# Iterate through a hash from the Rails controller in js

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, view, controller, haml

In my rails controller i have made an hash which looks like this:

```
@data = {

 term => {        
   node_id => {
    :name,
    :matchcode,
    :credits,
    :parts => [{
      :mp_id,
      :matchcode,
      :nr,
      :selected
    }]

}}
```

Now i want to iterate in js through this hash to get the keys and values.
At first I need the term i tried to get it with something like:

```
for(var s in '#{@data}') {
   console.log(s);
}
```

But i seems like I did something wrong it's the first time i use rails..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing data from the server side ruby controller to client side javascript code is not that simple. Firstly, javascript has no idea about ruby variables, the above is simply string `'#{data}'` which evaluates to itself.

There are couple of ways of passing such a data:

Firstly, you can set an html attribute on DOM element server side and then read it in your javascript. This might be simplest solution when passing a string or a number, for a hash however it is quite messy as you need to convert it into a form understandable by javascipt - into JSON. Even though it is very simple to do, it just adds extra complexity and is just dirty.

Second option is a [gon](https://github.com/gazay/gon) gem. It provides you with an object you can assign data to in your controller. Then it handles all the transformations and you can access all the data in your javascript:

```
# controller
gon.my_data = {a: 1}

#js
gon.myData  #=> {"a": 1}
```

This solution is very simple, however it still feels a little bit dirty.

Final, cleanest and more complex solution is to use AJAX - your javascript makes a request to your server to receive the data. Might be an overkill in many situation.

Comment: Thank you for this usefull answer, is it possible/recommended to translate all js code to haml + ruby with only a small part js  to get the iteration trough haml?